# Active nav item

Tags: javascript, navigation

I've got some code to add class `active` to navigation when the user scrolls to a certain div. I also use vue.js and have some components that don't use the navigation. In these components (where I don't use navigation) I get the error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
     var y = $(this).scrollTop();
     $('.link').each(function (event) {
       // this code allows me to disable script when there's no navigation
       if(!event.length) {
         return;
       }
       if (y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top) {
          $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
       }
     });
  });
});
```

This code allows me to disable script when there's no navigation but it also breaks the rest of the code so on the main page with navigation, there's no class added.

```
  if(!event.length) {
     return;
   }
```

Comment: Where do you expect to get `event` from in the handler for the `.each()` method?

Comment: When I try to use `event` in `.scroll()` method it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check it `if(!event && !event.length)`, sorry for that I had to edit it many times

Comment: Works but also the `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` error appears.

Comment: Yes, I was going to post this too `$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top`
need to make sure first there is an `<a>` to get the top offset

Comment: With `||` doesn't work.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` will get you the value of href if the selected element is `<a>` but what offset, share your HTML may help understand the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166132/discussion-between-abdelrahman-mohamed-allam-and-kabugh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the element is not undefined

```
if($($(this).attr('href')).offset() != undefined && y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top)
```

I edited this answer:

```
.each(function(index, element){})
```

you can see here `event` here is just the name of variable and if it logged into the console you will find it represent the index  `$('.link').each(function (event){})`
so `event.length` is meaningless
 ref:. https://api.jquery.com/each/

- `.link` selector tend to be for the collection of anchor links
- `$($(this).attr('href'))`  `<a href="#selectorId">menu item</a>` so if your  element has no `href` with offset if would throw `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you expect `event' to be a collection in this bit of code:

```
   if(!event.length) {
     return;
   }
```

This code:

```
$('.link').each(...)
```

passes a single item from the jQuery collection created by `$('.link'), and it appears that single item should be and HTMLAnchorElement. The HTMLAnchorElement does not have a`length`property. The length property comes through the inheritance heirarchy for the`` tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

It appears your intent might be to do something like this in pseudo code:

1. grab all the links (put them into a collection)
2. if there are no links (length of the collection is zero)
   Don't do anything
3. Otherwise (there are links)
   For each link find the one to highlight
   Add the `active` class to that element

This is **NOT** what your code does.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer, but the answer below worked for me.

Comment: Take a look at your code. That answer works, but I'm interested in you seeing the logic error you have in your code. Please review my answer.

Comment: Yes, now I do understand what was the problem, thanks, will try to enhance my code.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.